# --JSX does not appear to render correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to simply output a list of `<p>` tags but do no know the correct syntax.

I verified the data is correctly stored in `this.props.bookmarks.bookmarks` but could not figure out how to render it correctly.

I verified that there is a `bookmark.title` property as well.

With in the React component `render()` function I have as follow:

```
return (

// ... snip

this.props.bookmarks.bookmarks.map((bookmark) => {
  return "<p>{bookmark.title}</p>";
});

// ... snipt

)
```

**Update:**

```
var titles = this.props.bookmarks.bookmarks.map((bookmark) => {

  return <div className='bookmark_div' id='generated1'>
    <img className='bookmark_image' id='generated2' src='http://arcmarks.com/_images/sv_favicon.svg'/>
    <a className='bookmark_link' id='generated3'>arcmarks</a>
  </div>

});
```

Comment: I know you said that `this.props.bookmarks.bookmarks` is correct, why isn't it `this.props.bookmarks` ? The code looks ok and should render if the data is as you say. Put a console.log before the render

Answer (score 3):

If you are outputting an iterable in this manner, React is going to throw a warning/error about keys, so you should attach a unique identifier also. React uses these keys to help optimize rendering as it monitors updates to the DOM.

It looks like this is embedded inside other JSX code also, so you may need to wrap it in `{}`

```
return (
  // ... snip

  {this.props.bookmarks.bookmarks.map((bookmark) => {
    return <p key={bookmark.id}>{bookmark.title}</p>;
  });}

  // ... snip
)
```

You could also optimize this further by destructuring the bookmarks iterable out, and utilize implicit return:

```
const { bookmarks } = this.props.bookmarks

return (
  // ... snip

  {bookmarks.map((bookmark) => <p key={bookmark.id}>{bookmark.title}</p>)}

  // ... snip
)
```

In my example, `bookmark.id` could be anything as long as it's unique, even `bookmark.title`.

To come full circle, I will just add an example that shows this inside some additional JSX/HTML so you can see it:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  // set initial button state to false
  this.state = {
    buttonClicked: false
  }
}

// method to handle button clicking
handleButton(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('Radical button firing.')
  // set state to opposite of current
  this.setState({ buttonClicked: !this.state.buttonClicked })
}

render() {
  if (!this.props.bookmarks) return <div>Loading...</div>

  const { bookmarks } = this.props.bookmarks

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Checkout my Rad Books</h3>

      {bookmarks.map((bookmark) => <p key={bookmark.id}>{bookmark.title}</p>)}

      <button onClick={(e) => this.handleButton(e)}>{(!this.state.buttonClicked) ? 'Not Clicked Yet' : 'Was Clicked'}</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When you render, you must always wrap in a parent element, in this case, we used a div. I included some wealthy data here so you can forensically analyze and test further.

We might aswell go all out here. We can pull that book list into a rendering method also:

```
renderBooks() {
  if (!this.props.bookmarks.bookmarks) return <div>Loading bookmarks...</div>

  const { bookmarks } = this.props.bookmarks

  return (
    <div>
      {bookmarks.map((bookmark) => <p key={bookmark.id}>{bookmark.title}</p>)}
    </div>
  )
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Checkout my Rad Books</h3>

      {this.renderBooks()}

      <button onClick={(e) => this.handleButton(e)}>{(!this.state.buttonClicked) ? 'Not Clicked Yet' : 'Was Clicked'}</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: you actualy have to use propety 'key' and not 'id'

Comment: Yes, it is `key={whatever.you.want}`

Comment: I just edited my answer to include example of handling the condition when books aren't loaded yet. Generally, you want to always handle this condition. You will see an error about "something of undefined" if it goes to render and some data is not populated yet.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have setup Babel (or some other transpiler) correctly:

```
return <p>{bookmark.title}</p>;
```

should work (no `"`s).

This will compile to:

```
React.createElement('p', null, bookmark.title);
```

(or something similar) in the resulting JS output.

If you want to render multiple lines of HTML, wrap your JSX in `()`s:

```
return (
<div>
    <p>content here</p>
</div>
)
```

Comment: @Mikkel, no it is not. Notice, this snippet does not have any `"`s around the paragraph tags.

Comment: As far as I know, JSX does not render strings and needs actual HTML elements. But, I think that he needs to wrap the map function with braces too

Comment: On top of that he also needs to add a `key` on `p` because he is mapping that in a loop

Comment: How can I render long lines of HTML like above in my updated question?

Comment: Taking out the quotes works but I need to extend the HTML ... also I pulled the function out side the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
return "<p>{bookmark.title}</p>";
```

You seem to be trying to interpolate. You shouldn't need to interpolate it.

```
return <p>{bookmark.title}</p> should be good.
```

If you're using ES6, you can interpolate using backticks.

```
`My name is ${name}`
```